# Jquery UI dialog in wordpress admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dialog

I am attempting to use the jQuery UI dialog script in my Wordpress theme admin page.  Everything is straight from the UI demo and yet I end up with a dialog box where the dialog is not popped up over anything and instead buried in bottom corner, just before the closing body tag.

The UI dialog script is queued properly w/ wp_enqueue_script as its shows up in the source code as does jquery (from google API) and the UI core.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
}); //end onload stuff
```

Then I have this in my options page:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: well i solved it.  looked at the demo again and there are apparently quite a few scripts being enqueued that aren't mentioned as dependencies.  

jquery.bgiframe-2.1.1.js.js , jquery.ui.widget.js , jquery.ui.mouse.js ,jquery.ui.draggable.js" ,jquery.ui.position.js , jquery.ui.resizable.js all seem to be needed in addition to the obvious jquery.ui.dialog.js

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should be all ready to go. WP already has dialog and styles for it.

Here are the steps to use it:

1. Write the jQuery for creating the dialog box - you must use the `dialogClass` of `wp-dialog`
2. Enqueue the above file on `init` using the proper dependencies (`jquery-ui-dialog`)
3. Enqueue the proper WP styles (`wp-jquery-ui-dialog`)

For example:

```
// custom.js
jQuery(function($) {
    var $info = $("#modal-content");
    $info.dialog({                   
        'dialogClass'   : 'wp-dialog',           
        'modal'         : true,
        'autoOpen'      : false, 
        'closeOnEscape' : true,      
        'buttons'       : {
            "Close": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#open-modal").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $info.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

In your PHP

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'queue_my_admin_scripts');

function queue_my_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script (  'my-spiffy-miodal' ,       // handle
                        URL_TO_THE_JS_FILE  ,       // source
                        array('jquery-ui-dialog')); // dependencies
    // A style available in WP               
    wp_enqueue_style (  'wp-jquery-ui-dialog');
}
```

Comment: once i made the following adjustments, this worked perfectly. 1. i got $info is not defined errors, b/c it is initially definded as $modalContents. so i replaced $modalContents w/ $info.  2. instead of enqueing this everywhere on the front-end... i added it to admin_init.  could probably get more specific to my particular admin page. THANKS!

Comment: @helga - Yeah, using `$info` was a typo, and `admin__init` is better - Thanks!

Comment: Oh my, really ugly dialog. I hope WordPress peeps improve the look of it. The X-closing button looks like it's from some other program, and whats with the borders? At least the WP native button look can be attained with this:  `'buttons' : [{'text' : 'Close', 'class' : 'button-primary', 'click' : function() { $(this).dialog('close');} }]` (notice the *button-primary* class)

Comment: @Ciantic WordPress is open source, so you can contribute your change. Check out the following link https://make.wordpress.org/core/

Answer (score 6):

I manged to show the dialog using the following code (but styling was not applied!):

```
add_action('init', 'myplugin_load');

function myplugin_load(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' );
}
```

When calling it used:

```
$("#dialog-view").dialog({
   height: 240,
   modal: true
});
```

Comment: if you enqueue `jquery-ui-dialog` its dependencies will also automatically be enqueued, so you don't need to add `jquery` and `jquery-ui-core`. You can just enqueue your JS like: `wp_enqueue_script('my-script-handle', URL_TO_MY_SCRIPT, array('jquery-ui-dialog'));`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it makes any difference (because I'm not in the right place to do any testing at the moment), but maybe try the code exactly as it is on the jQuery UI site:

```
$(function() {
   $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

Best of luck! ^.^

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't solve it.  i've read that you have to use jQuery(document).ready(function($) { }); to wrap jquery functions in WP and have found that to be true w/ the couple other things i have managed to make work

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Add Script :**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' );// in your function.php or plugin
```

**Step 2: Create Dialog Box :**

```
  <div id="dialog-content" style="display:none;" class="dialog-content"> <div style="padding:100px;text-align:center;">Your Custom Content </div></div>
```

Create a hidden content box. So you can show it as a dialog box. Finally attach a click event to a button to call the dialog box.

**Step 3: Call the Dialog :**

```
  //attach a click event then call the dialog 
  $('#dialog-calling-btn').click(function () {

    $("#dialog-content").dialog({
      'dialogClass': 'wp-dialog email-quote-box',
      'title': 'Title',
      'modal': true,
      'autoOpen': true,
      'closeOnEscape': true,
      'height': 500,
      'width': 360
    });
  })
```